# Is there any package to create bullet gauge graphs?

Tags: graphics

I am looking for a package to create bullet gauge graphs, but I couldn't find any.

A bullet graph looks like this:

[image]

and an ample description/specification can be found [here](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/misc/Bullet_Graph_Design_Spec.pdf)

It is available in Mathematica 9 ([see here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/gauges/bullet-gauges.html))

Is it possible create this kind of graphs in a easy way with `TeX` (like Matehmatica 9 or similar)?

Comment: in general: `tikz` is great

Comment: Are you sure they are called ´bullet diagrams´? I'm not questioning your english, but rather the way to look for a package at CTAN(http://ctan.org)

Comment: @MarioS.E., Yes, i´m suer, because the creator of this kind of graphs is Stephen Few, and the specifications (by the author) are: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/misc/Bullet_Graph_Design_Spec.pdf

Comment: @MikaIke to my knowledge there is no direct package in CTAN for dealing with bullet diagrams... but as mentioned as @Micha, the `Tikz` is very versatile and you should be able to replicate what you want.  I think the samples you showed were made with Excel.  You can always use them as figures in your LaTeX file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be relatively easily achieved using PGFPlots. I've written a small macro that is called like this:

```
\bulletgauge[title={\bfseries{\large Revenue}\\1000 USD}]{275}{260}{300,250,150}
```

to create this:

[image]

The optional argument can be used to pass normal PGFPlots options to the `axis` environment used internally.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\definecolor{ylgnbu1}{RGB}{237, 248, 177}
\definecolor{ylgnbu2}{RGB}{127, 205, 187}
\definecolor{ylgnbu3}{RGB}{44, 127, 184}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{bullet}{
{fill=ylgnbu1, draw=none},
{fill=ylgnbu2, draw=none},
{fill=ylgnbu3, draw=none},
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
Label;  Sublabel;   Measure;    CompMeasure; Range1; Range2; Range3
Revenue 2005 YTD;   USD;    260;    255;150;250;300
}\datatable

\newcommand{\bulletgauge}[4][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y=1.5ex,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=0, xmax=300,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0ex},
        tick align=outside,
        axis on top,
        every axis title/.style={
            at={(rel axis cs:0,0.5)},
            anchor=east,
            align=right,
            xshift=-1em
        },
        #1
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{#4}{
        \pgfplotsset{cycle list name=bullet}
        \addplot +[xbar, bar width=3ex] coordinates {(##1,0)};
    }
    \addplot [fill=black, xbar, bar width=1ex] coordinates {(#2,0)};    
    \addplot [mark=|, mark options={very thick}, mark size=1.25ex] coordinates {(#3,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\bulletgauge[title={\bfseries{\large Revenue}\\1000 USD}]{275}{260}{300,250,150}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jake. I admire your work.

I think that comunity need your bullet guage package! :-)

For me is enough, but i like your creation.

Comment: Really Fantastic. Yes :-))
You have created the solution.
I would anime you to create a special package for this kind of graphs. It´s very usefull and each day it´s more popular and known.
You have created the basic (and more dificult) graph, but.... like you are capable, I think that you would make well creating more options, and your own package.

Mathematica offer to bullet gauges many features, as you can see:
http://imageshack.us/a/img35/1061/snap2134.png

For me it´s enough to see your creation, but ... I think that you can create a new and usefull package.

Comment: You have created the solution.

I would anime you to create a special package for this kind of graphs. It´s very usefull and each day it´s more popular and known.


Mathematica offer many and interesting bullet gauges, if you like to see. I think that it´s good add the possibility of any other bars and/or marks

For me it´s enough to see your cretion, but ... I think that you can create a new and usefull package.