# To where/whom should I write for an invitation to create a tool for bullet graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

I was wondering if creating "bullet gauges" is possible in any LaTeX package, but I didn´t find any.

In other question @Jake answered me with a solution for simple graphs in [Is there any package to create bullet gauge graphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117314/is-there-any-package-to-create-bullet-gauge-graphs)

I want to talk to somebody about this, because I think that it's a good contribution to LaTeX, and I'd like to invite to consider creating this kind of graphs as a new addition in the future, I think the use of this kind of graphs is increasing.

You can see bullet gauge original directives here, Stephen Few is the creator of this kind of graph:

http://www.perceptualedge.com/blog/?p=375

Here you can see with more data:

http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2009/slides/Porzak.pdf

In the version 9 of Mathematica, thee are a lot of options like you can see here:

[image]

I think that it may be useful reading data from files.

Comment: Probably this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117314/is-there-any-package-to-create-bullet-gauge-graphs?rq=1 will be suitable for you.

Comment: @Prxzemyslaw-scherwentke  Yes, but I was suggested to split an comment in two independent questions. That´s the reason because I answer here.

Comment: @MikaIke: actually, you're allowed to post links to other site's questions/answers, but as Martin said you it is better to not use `here`. You might consider to copy and paste the url and in this way the title will automatically appear ad percusse did a minute ago.